# Check validation before continuing with AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've taken on someone else project and trying to figure things out as I'm new to JS.

I need the AJAX request to be called when the button is clicked but also if the validation is true then to wait for the answer from the dialog and abort if 'No' has been selected and continue if 'Yes' is selected.

At the moment is continues with the AJAX post and shows the dialog at the same time when I tried using beforeSend.

Any sort of direction would be of great help.

Thanks

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  var startdate = moment(year + "-" + month + "-" + day,'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var lastActionLogEffectiveDt = $('#lastActionLogEffectiveDate').val();
  var lastActionLogEffectiveDate = moment(lastActionLogEffectiveDt).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

  $.ajax({
      url: myUrl,
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend : function(xhr){
        if(startdate <= lastActionLogEffectiveDate) {
            tools.helpers.confirm({title:'Warning', message:'</p><p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>', buttons:{yes:1, no:1}, type:'warning'}).then(
              function(answer) {
                if(answer == 'no') {
                  xhr.abort();
                }
            });
        } 
      },
  }).done(function(resp) {
    if(!resp) {
      reloadPage();
    }
    else
    {
      validationUtil.removeAllErrorsFromPage();
      validationUtil.populateErrorPane(resp);           
    } 
  }).fail(function() {
      validationUtil.removeAllErrorsFromPage();
      validationUtil.populateErrorPane("Error processing payment actions, please try again.");
  })
  return false;

});
```

Comment: according to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), to cancel the request beforeSend should return false. You aren't doing that.

Comment: You may use an if statement before the ajax call to check if user selected 'Yes' and only then make the ajax call, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about wrapping the AJAX Request in your dialog condition rather than doing it in 'beforeSend'? That way the request wont start until the dialog has been interacted with.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  var startdate = moment(year + "-" + month + "-" + day,'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var lastActionLogEffectiveDt = $('#lastActionLogEffectiveDate').val();
  var lastActionLogEffectiveDate = moment(lastActionLogEffectiveDt).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

  if (startdate <= lastActionLogEffectiveDate) {
    tools.helpers.confirm({ title:'Warning', message:'</p><p>Are you sure you want to continue?</p>', buttons:{ yes: 1, no: 1 }, type:'warning' })
    .then(function (answer) {

      if(answer === 'yes') {

        $.ajax({
          url: myUrl,
          type: "POST"
        }).done(function (resp) {
          if(!resp) {
            reloadPage();
          } else {
            validationUtil.removeAllErrorsFromPage();
            validationUtil.populateErrorPane(resp);           
          } 
        }).fail(function () {
          validationUtil.removeAllErrorsFromPage();
          validationUtil.populateErrorPane("Error processing payment actions, please try again.");
        })

      }

    });
  } 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: What if I want the ajax request to run if button is clicked and if the validation is kicked in then it will also run when user selects Yes otherwise abort - hope that makes sense?